# Ubisoft server problem in every AC game

Tags: xbox-360, assassins-creed-4-black-flag, ubisoft-connect, assassins-creed-rogue

I've searched for a solution to this problem for days, all together. I can't seem to get it fixed.

Since AC4:Black Flag the game is saying the Ubisoft Server are offline. Every time. It's a little annoying in Black Flag because I can't play Kenways's fleet. But now I have Rogue and it tells me the exact same thing.

So far I've tried:
- Resetting my xbox connection;
- Port forwarding and placing my xbox in the DMZ;
- Switching router firmware (I have a ASUS RT-AC66u and I've tried DD-WRT, standard and Merlin);
- I never have any problems with the MP of any other game;
- I've downloaded all the patches obviously;

Does anyone recognize this problem?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Ubi's customer support? This seems like a problem with their server, seeing as other games work fine. Also, don't just DMZ your console, that's very unsafe. But you sound like you know that already ;)

Comment: @Kevin, Yes I prefer port forwarding, but I've tried just about everything, to be sure. And I have contacted support and created a ticket. But I can hardly believe this is a bug of some sort that would affect only me. But stranger things have happened. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is there anything special about your internet configuration? Are you behind a [symmetric NAT](http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/09/19/symmetric-nat/)? Did you try turning on [upnp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play)? Is there a content filter somewhere along the line (some hotels etc do this)?

Comment: I believe my internet config is as default as they come. Installing the router with new firmware or it's default firmware and clearing the nvram in the process I can't really think of anything that is out of the ordinary in my case. I've indeed tried enabling uPnp. It made no difference. And I don't have a content filter, I'm just your average Ziggo home user. The term symmetric NAT is new to me, I'll read up using the link you provided.

Comment: Symmetric NAT is mainly used for 3G or LTE, I don't think non-mobile lines use it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is Uplay a downloadable app on 360? If so, download that and check if you are able to log in.

Comment: @Brok3n I'll check this tonight. Thx.